# How do you call postMessage() from a vue service worker

Tags: vue.js, vuejs2, service-worker

We have a vue firebase service worker that needs to call back to the main vue app. According to my research you can do this with the postMessage() function like so:

```js
// firebase-messaging-sw.js

addEventListener('fetch', event => {
  event.waitUntil(
    (async function() {
      // Exit early if we don't have access to the client.
      // Eg, if it's cross-origin.
      if (!event.clientId) return

      // Get the client.
      const client = await clients.get(event.clientId)
      // Exit early if we don't get the client.
      // Eg, if it closed.
      if (!client) return

      // Send a message to the client.
      client.postMessage({
        msg: 'Hey I just got a fetch from you!',
        url: event.request.url
      })
    })()
  )
})
```

You handle the message in the main app so:

```js
// main.js

navigator.serviceWorker.addEventListener('message', event => {
  console.log('Url', event.data.url)
  console.log('msg', event.data.msg)
})
```

The problem is that postMessage() needs to be called on a client object and you get the client object on the fetch event, but vue does not seem to fetch anything as it is a single page application. 
So how can I get the client? 
and how do I message the main app?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The client does not need to make a fetch request in order to allow the Service Worker to communicate with it. You can use the Clients API inside the Service Worker. You can also initiate a completely separate postMessage message from the client in the beginning after the app has started.

Clients API: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Clients

I also suggest you check out this example: https://serviceworke.rs/message-relay.html